# React does not update state immediately and wait for function to bring back data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, webpack

I have a comonent that gets data from Java in callBackFunction untill that function gets back i want to show a spinner but when i run this it does not show me spinner it just waits for the data to come back and then show the main component. I am new to react please help me.

```js
class MyFirstComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
    };
    this.getMyObject = this.getMyObject.bind(this);
  }

  async getMyObject() {

    this.currentObject = await this.props.callBackFunction(JSON.stringify(request));
    await this.setStateAsync({
      isLoading: false
    });
  }

  setStateAsync(state) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.setState(state, resolve);
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getMyObject();
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return <SpinnerWidget size = "small" / > ;
    }

    return <MyMainComponent/>;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You used a wrong tag, this question has nothing to do with _Java_ but _JavaScript_ :).

Comment: Can you try defining `componentDidMount` as `async componentDidMount`?. See [here](https://codepen.io/angelaraya/pen/JjjWxZe) for a working example.

Comment: @ÁngelAraya thanks for the code, it works but my question is that can we do this without setTimeOut function

Comment: @Rayyan the setTimeout is there to simulate an async operation, you could replace it with your callback function and it should work.